How to define arg max in Coq
I'm new to Coq. I'm interested in defining a recursive function c(k). The base case c(0) is the constant 0. Given c(k), there is a(k+1, i) = g(i, c(k)) where g is a function, and c(k+1) = a(k+1, j), where j = arg max h(a(k+1, i)) over all 0 <= i <= T, h is another function, and T is an upper bound on i. c(k) and a(k) are both natural numbers. The indices are natural numbers. I'm stuck at defining the arg max operator.
Here is my sketch:
(* The upper bound of i *)
Parameter T : nat.
Parameter g : nat -> nat -> nat.
Parameter h : nat -> nat.

Fixpoint c (k : nat) : nat :=
  match k with
  | 0 => 0
  | S k' => a k j  (* ?? *)
  with
Fixpoint a (k i : nat) : nat :=
  match k with
  | 0 => 0
  | S k' => g i (c k')
  end.

I asked GPT about it, and it suggests me to first find the max of h(a(k+1, i)) over i, and then search for the specific i that produce that max value. Apparently this does not work, because the searching yields an option of nat, but I know arg max is not an option.
Thank you so much!

ChatGPT is not far off the mark here.  Searching returns an option nat, because you might be searching for a value that does not exist.   But you know that the value exists, so you know that the search will always return a value of the form Some x.  From this knowledge, you can safely get rid of the exceptional case, by running your searching result through a function of the following form.
Definition discard_option (x : option nat) : nat :=
  match x with Some x => x | _ => 0 end.

When proving properties about the code, you will have to show that find (the function you can use to search for the right value) never returns None, of course.
You could also use T as the value returned, because this value is outside the range that should normally be reached.

Actually, another issue I feel problematic with GPT's answer is that, if h is identity map, the definition of arg max should reflect the property forall i, c(k+1) >= a(k+1, i) and the property exists i, c(k+1) = a(k+1,i); and GPT's answer fails to achieve it. For other h, I can't think of such properties, but I feel it quite unnatural to define arg max like this, in that it's not mathematical, but rather programmatic.
